# Dynamically created object (providing its classname as a string) do not call its constructor

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Here is the object:

```
TCell = class(TPersistent)
private
  FAlignmentInCell :byte;
public
  constructor Create; virtual;
published
  property AlignmentInCell:byte  read FAlignmentInCell write FAlignmentInCell;
end;
```

this is its constructor:

```
constructor TCell.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  FAlignmentInCell:=5;
end;
```

Here is a function, which dynamically creates any object derived form TPersistent (parameter is class name provided as a string)

```
function  CreateObjectFromClassName(AClassName:string):TPersistent;
var DynamicObject:TPersistent;
    TempObject:TPersistent;
    DynamicPersistent:TPersistent;
    DynamicComponent:TComponent;
    PersistentClass:TPersistentclass;
    ComponentClass:TComponentClass;
begin
  PersistentClass:=TPersistentclass(FindClass(AClassName));
  TempObject:=PersistentClass.Create;
  if TempObject is TComponent then
         begin
         ComponentClass:=TComponentClass(FindClass(AClassName));
         DynamicObject:=ComponentClass.Create(nil);
         end;
  if not (TempObject is TComponent) then
         begin
         DynamicObject:=PersistentClass.Create; // object is really TCell, but appropriate constructor seems to be not called. 
         end;
  result:=DynamicObject;
end;
```

My idea is to create new Cell (TCell) like this:

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var p:TPersistent;
begin
  p := CreateObjectFromClassName('TCell');
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(TCell(p).AlignmentInCell)); // it is 0. (Why?)
end;
```

When I want to check AlignmentInCell property I get 0, but I expected 5. Why? Is there way to fix it?

Comment: You can verify your assumption by debugging. `TObject.Create` is called, **not** `TCell.Create`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar to a recent question.

You use `TPersistentClass`. But `TPersistent` does not have a virtual constructor, so the normal constructor for `TPersistent` is called, which is the constructor it inherits from `TObject`.

If you want to call the virtual constructor, you will have to declare a

```
type
  TCellClass = class of TCell;
```

Now you can modify `CreateObjectFromClassName` to use this metaclass instead of `TPersistenClass`, and then the **actual** constructor will be called.

Also, `TempObject` is never freed. And instead of `is`, I would rather use `InheritsFrom`.

I did not test the following, but it should work:

```
function CreateObjectFromClassName(const AClassName: string; AOwner: TComponent): TPersistent;
var 
  PersistentClass: TPersistentclass;
begin
  PersistentClass := FindClass(AClassName);
  if PersistentClass.InheritsFrom(TComponent) then
    Result := TComponentClass(PersistentClass).Create(AOwner)
  else if PersistentClass.InheritsFrom(TCell) then
    Result := TCellClass(PersistentClass).Create
  else
    Result := PersistentClass.Create;
end;
```

Comment: Yes, I really defined TCellClass = class of TCell; and called it explicitly DynamicObject:=TCellClass(FindClass(AClassName)).Create; 
And really all descendants of TCell are created by their own constructor.
I will check up your suggestion, and fix minor flaws... Thanx

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can't know for sure what value your variable of type `TPersistentClass` will hold at run time. So he assumes that it is exactly that: a `TPersistentClass`.

`TPersistentClass` is defined as a `class of TPersistent`. `TPersistent` has no virtual constructor, the compiler will therefore not include a call to dynamically look up the address of the constructor in the VMT of the actual class, but a 'hard-coded' call to the only matching constructor `TPersistent` has: the one it inherits from its base class TObject.

It might be a decision with reasons I don't know, but if you had chosen to define `TCell` as following

```
TCell = class(TComponent)
private
  FAlignmentInCell: byte;
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
published
  property AlignmentInCell:byte  read FAlignmentInCell write FAlignmentInCell;
end;
```

you wouldn't need `TempObject` and all the decision making in your `CreateObjectFromClassName` function (and the possible leaks as pointed out by others):

```
function CreateObjectFromClassName(AClassName:string): TComponent;
var 
  ComponentClass:TComponentClass;
begin
  ComponentClass:=TComponentClass(FindClass(AClassName));
  Result := ComponentClass.Create(nil);  
end;
```

And make sure to manage the `Result`s life-time as it has no `Owner`.